# How to do the "inverse" of Rails' simple_format?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, string-conversion

The `simple_format` helper in Rails will take text input and convert newline characters to `p` or `br` tags which is the exact opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish.

How would i go about taking a snippet of HTML that looks like:

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum.
  <br /> 
  Lorem ipsum.
  <br /> 
  Lorem ipsum. 
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum.
</p>
```

And convert it to something that looks like:

```
Lorem\n\nIpsum.\nLorem ipsum.\nLorem ipsum.\n\nLorem ipsum.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_html = html
             .gsub("\n", '')             # remove existing new lines
             .gsub('</p>', "</p>\n")     # add a new line per para tag
             .gsub('<br />', "<br />\n") # add a new line per break tag
ActionController::Base.helpers
  .strip_tags(new_html)                  # remove all html tags
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would you be willing to update your answer with an explanation behind what you're doing. Specifically, what was the reason to run it through `strip_tags`?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing previous answer you might want to add `.gsub('<br/>', "<br/>\n")` in case break tags are this way and `.gsub('<div/>', "<div/>\n")`. Just make sure you are replacing all tags that must break the text.